# Workaround for Outlook 2007 for wrapping text around image with margin?

Tags: html, image, email, outlook, outlook-2007

As we all know, Outlook 2007 uses the Word 2007 rendering engine, causing endless grief when designing HTML email message. [Insert rant here] In particular, float, margin, and padding are - shall we say? - poorly supported.

To simulate float so that text wraps around an image, apparently we can simply use:

```
<img src="foo.png" align="right">
```

The issue is padding/margin. Without padding/margin, the wrapped text butts up against the image which looks goofy. One workaround is to edit the image and add transparent framing that simulates margin.

Does anyone know any other workarounds?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have tried it this morning and sadly borders on images arnt supported, however, you can implement the concept on the text area :).

border-left: 7px solid #fff;

for example, inside a white container would give the visual effect of left padding....

Comment: yeah this worked really well for me in Outlook Mac 2010, and Hotmail.com/ Outlook.com.  Its a really nice base level style that obviously plays nice in Webkit and Gmail becuase its not inherently a hack. +1  Dont support Outlook 2007 any more anyway, its practially 2014!

Comment: Sorry - my bad. This actually does nothing in Outlook 2007!

Answer (score 19):

After reading Microsoft's documentation on Outlook 2007 support, I found that using hspace on an image will work to create white space around it similar to padding.

[ img src="image.jpg" align="left" border="0" hspace="10" ]

That will give you the equivalent of 10px of padding. Works pretty well across email clients.

Figured I'd share in case someone else Googling the issue stumbles across this question like I did.

Comment: + 1 Thank you very much for adding this. I was indeed trying to find an answer to this problem. I didn't want to use CSS as it is not well supported across all email clients. This helps a great deal.

Comment: HSPACE has worked for me as well - seems to be the simple solution.  VSPACE is also available of course for top/bottom padding.

Answer (score 6):

One place that padding is supported in Outlook '07 is `<td>` tags.  So I have solved this by wrapping the image in a table:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="left">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="left">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td valign="top" style="padding: 0px 10px 0 0;">
                <img src="http://www.mysite.com/images/myimage.jpg" style="width:60px; height:100px;" border="0" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
        <p>The text I want to see wrap...</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Note the `align="left"` is on the parent table as well as the one immediately holding the image.  This hack is needed for Outlook 2013.  Everything else looked great without it on Litmus.

Comment: You could also use a <td width="10"> after the cell containing the image instead of using css padding.

Comment: @JacobDorman & Ecksley. I've tried both padding on the td container and adding a additional td after the image. Both resulting in a padding-like effect. BUT - for some reason the first 5px or so of my text is cut off. Like the left aligned table is on top my text and hiding it. Have you guys experienced that?

Answer (score 2):

Adding padding around in image for Outlook and all other email clients. 
I found that this works.

```
img {  
    padding-left: 25px!important;  
    padding-top: 25px!important;  
    padding-bottom: 25px!important;  
    padding-right: 25px!important;  
}
```

Comment: From my testing Outlook 2007/2010 do not support margin, padding or border on img.

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is old, but an alternative would be to give the image a solid border the same colour as the container.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. ;-) Interesting idea. Let me play with that and if it works, then I'll accept the answer. [Unfortunately, I'm swamped at the moment, so give me some time to clear my workload and then I'll check it out.]

Comment: doesn't work mate - [Outlook 2007 doesn’t show image borders](http://www.email-standards.org/blog/entry/outlook-2007-doesnt-show-image-borders/)

Answer (score -3):

If you add a inline style to the img tag with a margin command like this:

```
<img src="foo.png" align="right" style="margin:5px;">
```

I'm guessing that is what you're trying to do.

Comment: or if you want to be even more exact  
  
<img src="foo.png" align="right" style="margin-left:5px;">

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But from my direct experience and subsequent research, that does not work. Outlook 2007 does not seem to support margin, whether specified inline or otherwise. Any other ideas?